# How to convert pixel byte array to bitmap image in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmap, arrays

I want to draw Image in windows phone 8 using pixel byte. so I get some pixel byte via c++ library(c++/CLI). But pixel data not include bitmap Header. It is just pixel byte array.
Is this possible to convert pixel data array to bitmap Image without bitmap header in windows phone?

```
    public void updateImage(byte[] byteArray, UInt32 bufferSize, int cvtWidth, int cvtHeight)
    {
        // I saw this source a lot of search. But It's not work. It makes some exeption.
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        bi.SetSource(memoryStream);

        ImageScreen.Source = bi;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a WriteableBitmap : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap

Then you can access it's PixelBuffer using AsStream and save that array to the stream.

```
//srcWidth and srcHeight are original image size, needed
//srcData is pixel data array
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(srcWidth, srcHeight); 

using (Stream stream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream()) 
{ 
    await stream.WriteAsync(srcData, 0, srcData.Length); 
}
```

**EDIT**

As Proglamour stated in WIndows Phone there is no PixelBuffer, but a property named Pixels which is an array exists.

It cannot be replaced but it's content can so this should work:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(srcWidth, srcHeight); 
Array.Copy(srcData, wb.Pixels, srcData.Length);
```

Comment: How to use WriteableBitmap? I try that. But I can't draw. Here is my code.

`MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(cvtWidth, cvtHeight);

wb.SetSource(byteArray.AsBuffer().AsStream()); // It occur exception

ImageScreen.Source = wb;`

Comment: Updated answer with example

Comment: Thanks for reply. But there is not PixelBuffer in windows phone 8. I think that It's work in windows 8.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I solved this problem because of your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. Thanks for your help Filip.

```
    public void updateImage(byte[] byteArray, UInt32 bufferSize, int cvtWidth, int cvtHeight)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(cvtWidth, cvtHeight);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 0, wb.Pixels, 0, byteArray.Length);
            //wb.Invalidate();
            ImageScreen.Source = wb;
        });
    }
```