# How to convert byte[] to BitmapImage in Windows Runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, optimization, windows-runtime

I've a byte array of images and want to show them in the UI.

My code works, but it takes so much memory and after ~10 images app crashes.

```c#
foreach (var cake in cakes)
{
    var bytes = await Helper.GetImage(cake.Url);

    if (bytes != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await memoryStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            using (var ras = memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream())
            {
                ras.Seek(0);

                await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
                {
                    WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(120, 120);
                    writeableBitmap.SetSource(ras);
                    cake.Thumbnail = writeableBitmap;
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The returned `bytes` value is a full-size image, but I want it as a thumbnail to take less memory.

I see in the profiler `Cycle Detected` too.

How to get a thumbnail of an image byte array in a more optimized way? What is the problem in my code which causes a memory leak?

Comment: Could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073015/

Comment: Nested `using`s are not good. It's better to avoid them. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx).